# Validate that integer is typed

Tags: python, validation, types, input, integer

I've looked up several of these questions and can't seem to apply it to my code correctly.  I'm definitely new to Python and developed a number guessing game for practice.  The last error handling I need is to make sure that anything typed that is not an integer, will return an error message.  I was hoping to use an "if" statement like I have for other conditions, but will work with what I can get.  Thanks!

(this is just a snippet.  i didn't include the entire program)

```
def gamestart():
    print(rndnumber)
    for GuessAmount in range (1,11):
        ActualGuess = int(input("Guess number " + str(GuessAmount) + ": "))  
        if ActualGuess < rndnumber:
            print("HIGHER!")
        if ActualGuess > rndnumber:
            print("LOWER!")
        if ActualGuess != rndnumber:
            GuessAmount == GuessAmount + 1
        if ActualGuess == rndnumber:
            print("You Win!")
            gameend()
    print("")
    print("Sorry, but you ran out of guesses.")
    print("")
    gameend()
```

Comment: You've got one too many equals signs here: `GuessAmount == GuessAmount + 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use try/except:

```
while True:
    guess = input("Guess number " + str(GuessAmount) + ": ")
    try:
        guess_int = int(guess)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "please enter only integers"
```

Now you have your (converted to integer) input in `guess_int`.
If it was impossible to convert the input to integer, user gets warning and enters number once again.

Comment: This reminds me of number 2 here -> http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html

Comment: Instead of `finished`, just use `break`. Also, change `except` to `except ValueError`.

Comment: is `guess` supposed to be a new variable, or is it supposed to take the place of `ActualGuess` .  I assumed you meant ActualGuess and replaced the code.  Still got errors.  I'll try second suggestion before posting errors.

Comment: I have fixed tha answer; now I use `ActualGuess` in the code.

Comment: @BrandonJ.Wood: Thank you Brandon, I'll be waiting

Comment: It worked perfectly!  Thank you so very much!!!  I only had to use parenthesis for the print function, since I'm using 3.3.  Awesome!  That program is done!  Woo